# prototype js Validator

Tags: validation, magento, prototypejs

Is it possible in Validator plugin for prototypejs to put error-messages in certain div.class ?

I've tried

`new Validation('.form-class', { containerClassName : '.other_div' })`

but without any effect. Any ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the [supplied validation](https://github.com/atetlaw/Really-Easy-Field-Validation) allows for user-defined class names but it does use some predefined class names (see the "CSS Hooks" section).

A quick look at the source shows this:

```
getAdvice : function(name, elm) {
    return $('advice-' + name + '-' + Validation.getElmID(elm)) || $('advice-' + Validation.getElmID(elm));
}
```

So you can create some DIV elements in advance with an ID which the script will find and use. So if the password field is called `password` you can prepare an element like this:

```
<div id="advice-password" class="other_div" style="display: hidden;"></div>
```

---

If that's still not enough there is another possibility. Copy the `/js/prototype/validation.js` file to your theme's `js` folder (so the original remains intact) then in one of your theme's layout XML files do something like this:

```
<default>
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/validation.js</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/validation.js</name></action>
</default>
```

You are now free to modify the script however you want.